# Recommendations on how to create an offline wrapper for usergrid?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, leveldb, usergrid, unqlite

The app will be written with Ionic (thus ported to iOS and Android). I am interested in Usergrid (as opposed to using Parse or Firebase), but I would need some offline functionality.

If I was going to create a wrapper that would do some cacheing, storing and syncing of data, what local datastore would people recommend using? UNQlite or LevelDB?

Also is there anything I should consider in advance, before I code tackle the problem?

Comment: My first question is why? There are many leaner options for local databases. Unless you need the RESTful APIs?

Comment: I need a BaaS and I thought it would be easier if I stored the data in both ways locally and remotely   That way there would be minimal modification of data as they are modeled the same on both ends, as the database schema is not trivial. Why what would you suggest?

Comment: I think you'd have an uphill battle if you tried to include Usergrid offline like that. It's incredibly robust and fault tolerant, but it's not really something I'd suggest for offline. I'd recommend you look at something native to your platform first, regardless of the effort it takes for you to build syncing between your BaaS and local storage.

Comment: I don't want to mod usergrid to be offline, I just want a local store that is checked first (when offline), that is nosql and updates and caches some of its data from usergrid. I essentially just want data that is rarely modified to be stored locally and a cache of recent data/most used data.

Comment: I didn't mean taking it offline. I meant adding offline capabilities. Eg Like couchbase lite

Comment: Sorry yeah I got that. Well, since it hasn't been done before, you're a pioneer! Building an offline sync tool shouldn't be too difficult, so long as you don't need any server side conflict resolution (or if you do, you'll have to implement it yourself).